# How to Randomize objects from a collection along a curve?

Tags: modifiers, objects, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, collections

Is there a way to randomize objects along the circle from my collection. I have three objects in my collection and currently they are evenly spread across the circle. Is there a way to randomize it, like " cube-cube-sphere-cube-cylinder-sphere (doesnt have to be this order, just an example of randomization) instead of sphere-cube-cylinder-sphere-cube-cyinder"

[image: This is what it currently looks like]

[image: This is the geometry nodes im using.]

Comment: just plugin a random value - integer - from 0 to 2 in your instance index input of your instance on point node.

Comment: and pleeeeeease, next time you post a picture of your node tree - post it so that we can read it without bleeding eyes - thx

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes I will post a better node tree picture next time. Sorry about that.